# jQuery performance on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, performance

Hi I have this page http://samarjit.net78.net/jquerybrowser/jquery.apitest.snapshot.xml which has large amount of data. The HMTL is generated by XSLT transformation by browser. When you click something on the left menu it shows filtered contents in the center. The same filtering can be done using right side search box. The same method with same parameters is called on click of `go` button as with the left menu.

Now when i refresh the page and do a couple of times the filtering using the left menu it works pretty fast. But once I filter using the textbox and press go it takes longer to filter. Then all subsequent filtering from the left menu also appears to be slow.

If you do not use the search box even once but keep on clicking the main menu it does not slow down.

This is quite strange and I experienced it only in *firefox 3.6.8 with FireBug, FireQuery, PixelPerfect, and Firefinder*. I tested without even opening FireBug.

In IE8 and Chrome it runs even faster than firefox in general and this slow down never happens.

Can someone test this at their end and tell me if this behavior is visible?

Comment: This link seems to go to a free web-page-hosting ad.

Comment: Apparently I removed that url. But this one is the new url: [http://samarjit.net78.net/jquerybrowser/jquery.apitest2.xml](http://samarjit.net78.net/jquerybrowser/jquery.apitest2.xml). This is the page [http://samarjit.net78.net/jquerybrowser/](http://samarjit.net78.net/jquerybrowser/) where all the xmls are available.

Comment: It's a bit late for an answer, but i was having a similar problem, and found your question. Are you using Linux? Also, try [this](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/07/drag-and-drop-performance-in-jquery-is-slow-here-is-the-fix/) :)